# Enable TextArea for editing with JQuery

Tags: javascript, c#, html, jquery

I need that when I click the button "Editar" it allows to edit the TextArea. I tried the code below but nothing happens. I tried prop, removeAttr, removeProp. All the same. Nothing changes.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SalvarJustificativa", "Riscos"))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <input type="text" name="co_tratamento_risco" id="co_tratamento_risco" value="@item.co_tratamento_risco" hidden />
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="md-form">
            <label for="tx_justificativa " class="mb-4 triangulo">Digite sua justificativa:</label>
            @Html.TextArea("tx_justificativa", @item.tx_justificativa, new { @class = "md-textarea form-control", @id = "tx_justificativa", @maxlength = "500", @style = "min-width: 100%", @rows = "5", @readonly = "true" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button id="btnEditarJust" type="button" class="btn btn-danger mt-4">Editar</button>
        <button id="btnSalvarJust" type="submit" class="btn btn-success mt-4" >Salvar</button>
    </div>
}
```

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnEditarJust").click(function () {
        $("tx_justificativa").removeAttr("readonly");

    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$("tx_justificativa")` will try to find DOM elements that look like this: **`<tx_justificativa>`**.

You need to use `$("#tx_justificativa")` instead, `#` looks for an element by id.